# Minimum upper bound for sum of the entries of the inverse covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, matrix-inverse, kernels

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $k$ is [RBF kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel)

$$k(x, x') := \exp \left(-\frac{\|x-x'\|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$

and let $\mathbf{K}$ be the following $n \times n$ covariance matrix

$$\mathbf{K} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & k(x_1, x_2) & \dots & k(x_1, x_n)\\
k(x_2, x_1) & 1 & \dots & k(x_2, x_n)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
k(x_n, x_1) & k(x_n, x_2) & \dots & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

In practice, the sum of the entries of matrix $\mathbf{K}^{-1}$ is small. How can I find the minimum upper bound for it?

Specifically, when $\mathbf{1} = [1, ... , 1] \in \mathbb{R}^n$, I am looking for $M$ such that

$$\mathbf{1} \mathbf{K}^{-1} \mathbf{1}^{T} \leq M$$

**Note:** A similar question has been asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188611/sum-of-the-entries-of-the-inverse-covariance-matrix), but unfortunately it is not answered. Moreover, another similar question has been asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45087/tight-bound-for-sum-of-entries-of-the-inverse-of-a-nonnegative-matrix), but the value of the entries are not determined.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What's known for $n=2$ or $n=3$?

Comment: @LevBorisov $n$ is a finite number. Let's say $n=1000$

Comment: and you want the bound to be uniform over $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov If you are talking about $M$. I think it is obvious that $M \in \mathbb{R}$. Because the left side ($\mathbf{1} \mathbf{K}^{-1} \mathbf{1}^{T}$) is a read number

Comment: I mean, should the same real constant $M$ work for all $n$ and all $x_1,\ldots,x_n$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes

Comment: You probably need some hypothesis on the xi, e.g., (a) bounded (something like ||x|| = 1) and (b) deterministic (for example, if the xi are all equal, the matrix K has no inverse). The reason for the bounded condition is that if you take, for example $x_1 = N, x_2 = N^2$, etc., your K is close to the identity and the sum is close to n...

Answer (score 0):

I am writing here some tests I did. I wait it is useful.

Note that $$\mathbf{1}^T \mathbf{K}^{-1} \mathbf{1} =(\mathbf{K}^{-1} \mathbf{1})^T\mathbf{K}(\mathbf{K}^{-1} \mathbf{1})=\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{K}\mathbf{y}=\|\mathbf{K}^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{y}\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^ny_i=\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{1}\leq n\|\mathbf{y}\|,$$ in which $\mathbf{1}$ is written as a column, $\mathbf{K}\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{1}$ and $\mathbf{K}^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is the [positive square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#By_diagonalization) of $\mathbf{K}.$
It follows that $$\|\mathbf{K}^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{y}\|^2=\|\mathbf{K}^{-\frac{1}{2}}\mathbf{1}\|^2\leq \|\mathbf{K}^{-\frac{1}{2}}\|^2\|\mathbf{1}\|^2=n\|\mathbf{K}^{-\frac{1}{2}}\|^2=n\frac{1}{\lambda_{min}(\mathbf{K})}.$$

You can see the equality $\mathbf{K}\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{1}$ as an interpolation problem $$g(x_j)=1, \qquad j=1,\,2,\,\ldots,\,n,$$ to find the function $$g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^ny_iK(x_i,x),$$ in the reproducing kernel space $\mathcal{H}_K$. It follows that (please see equation (10) in [this text](http://amadeus.csam.iit.edu/%7Efass/PDKernels.pdf))
$$1=g(x_j)=\langle g,K(x_j,\cdot)\rangle\leq \|g\|\|K(x_j,\cdot)\|=\left(\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{K}\mathbf{y}\right)\sqrt{K(x_j,x_j)}.$$

You can find more results on reproducing kernels searching for "\(g(x)=\langle g,K^x\rangle \) " on SearchOnMath, for instance.

**Remark:** If you have some bound on $\min_{i\neq j}|x_i-x_j|$ then [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) can helps.